# How to render latex code in a string from an rmarkdown code chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown, equation, mathjax

In R, using an ordinary rmarkdown code chunk (ordinary here means opposite of inline code), how to render some latex code?

Here's an illustrative example:

````
---
title: "beta test"
output:
  html_document
---

```{r}
a = 42
b = "$\\beta$"
c = "$a + 2$"
d = "a + 2"
a
b
c
d
```

`r a`

`r b`

`r c`

`r d`
````

that generates:

[image]

I would like to render the latex code, e.g., the `$\\beta$` as it is in the case of the inline code.

My ultimate goal is to generate rendered latex code programmatically from "triple backticks" code chunks.

Answer (score 1):

That's Mathjax code rather than LaTeX. `output:html_document` indicates that you're producing a `html` doc.

Anyway, you may try `results="asis"` and use just one backslash `\beta`. However, this seems not to be compatible anymore with inline code; a workaround would be to use two variables.

````
---
 title: "beta test"
 output:
   html_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
 a = 42
 b = "$\\beta$"
 b1 = "$\beta$"
 c = "$a + 2$"
 d = "a + 2"
 a
 b
 b1
 c
 d
```

`r a`

`r b`

`r b1`

`r c`

`r d`
````

### Produces

[image]

The inline code